# Return child that matches in nested loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-loops

I'm trying to figure out how I can return the child in a nested loop in React. The data object contains a list of documents which each contains a list of files. This is what I have so far:

```
 const match = (data.documents.find((document) =>
        document.files.find(
            (file) => file.fileType === 'pdf',       
        ),
    );
```

This almost works, but the problem is that here match is set to the document of the matching file, and I want it to be updated to the matching file .. Any input on how I can change it to return the file object instead?

Edit: I only want the first match to be returned and then break out of the loops.

Comment: Instead of find can you use filter? Because filter will return the matched data.

Comment: It seems that filter() returns an array with matching elements, where I only want the first match to be returned .. So don't think that would work as intended, but thanks @AbuSufian

Comment: From that returned array you can pick first element !

Comment: That's what `find` does--returns the element that satisfies the predicate. If that isn't what you want to do then `find` isn't really the best option; iterating and breaking, filtering and taking the first, etc. are all viable options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) first to get all your files in a single array, then call [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on that one to get the first match:

```js
const documents = [{
  files: [
    { name: 'a.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'b.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'c.png', fileType: 'png' },
  ],
}, {
  files: [
    { name: 'd.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'e.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'f.pdf', fileType: 'pdf' },
  ],
}, {
  files: [
    { name: 'g.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'h.pdf', fileType: 'pdf' },
    { name: 'i.png', fileType: 'png' },
  ],
}]

const files = documents.map(doc => doc.files).flat();

console.log(files);

const match = files.find(file => file.fileType === 'pdf');

console.log(match);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you need all the files that match, then use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const documents = [{
  files: [
    { name: 'a.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'b.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'c.png', fileType: 'png' },
  ],
}, {
  files: [
    { name: 'd.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'e.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'f.pdf', fileType: 'pdf' },
  ],
}, {
  files: [
    { name: 'g.png', fileType: 'png' },
    { name: 'h.pdf', fileType: 'pdf' },
    { name: 'i.png', fileType: 'png' },
  ],
}]

const matches = documents.map(doc => doc.files).flat().filter(file => file.fileType === 'pdf');

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Your first suggestion worked perfectly, thank you! think I need to look a bit into the flat() method, that one did the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
const documents = [{files: [{fileType: 'jpeg'}, {fileType: 'docx'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'docx'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'docx'}, {fileType: 'pdf'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'jpeg'}]}];
let index;
const match = documents.find((document) =>
  document.files.some(
    // store the index of the matched fileType
    (file, i) => file.fileType === 'pdf' ? (index = i, true) : false,       
  ),
);
console.log(match.files[index]);
```

Or with basic for...of

```js
const documents = [{files: [{fileType: 'jpeg'}, {fileType: 'docx'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'docx'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'docx'}, {fileType: 'pdf'}]}, {files: [{fileType: 'jpeg'}]}];
let matchBreak;

Doc: for(let document of documents) {
  for(let file of document.files) {
    if(file.fileType === 'pdf') {
     matchBreak = file;
     break Doc;
    }
  }
}

console.log(matchBreak);

function findFile(documents) {
  for(let document of documents) {
    for(let file of document.files) {
      if(file.fileType === 'pdf') {
       return file;
      }
    }
  }
}

const matchReturn = findFile(documents);
console.log(matchReturn);
```